# Is there a coordinate system specifically designed for oblique map viewing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I've long been impressed with maps that have an oblique perspective that also provides the viewer with a sense of the earth's curvature.  National Geographic maps for decades often have had this type of view, wherein scale varies as the earth recedes into the distance.  Similarly, here's a 2013 example from the New York Times:

[image]
[(Source)](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2013/03/01/world/americas/border-graphic.html)

I get the sense that I'm looking down from a spaceship.  Google Earth gives a similar impression:

[image]

All of my previous mapping has used a traditional vertical view, so I thought that I would expand my cartographic skills by learning how to create that "oblique, bulging-earth effect" with Arc Desktop, using the New York Times map above as a reference.

I couldn't find any advice on how to proceed, so I experimented with a variety of coordinate systems.  the best that I came up with was the Vertical Perspective (World) (ESRI also refers to it as the World Vertical Perspective):

[image]

(For this example I modified the Longitude of Center to -150.0 to give the map the off-center, angled view towards the northeast.)

I think that this is not too bad.  I included latitude and longitude lines to confirm that the image indeed curved and bulged.

This was an interesting process which helped me to see how a variety of coordinate systems (and their settings) affected the map.

Now that I've found something that *appears* to work I'm wondering... **are there any coordinate systems specifically designed to create the "oblique, bulging-earth effect" that I'm looking for?**

It occurs to me that there may be some who object to my use of the phrase "Coordinate System", preferring that I use "Spatial Reference" or something else.  To fend off such diversions, I am merely following ESRI's nomenclature, as pictured below.

[image]

Comment: I don't think any projections are designed with that in mind. This "oblique, bulging-earth effect" you describe is because - and this may come as a shock to you - the earth is spherical! Any perspective projection (orthographic, isometric) will do this.

Comment: You say the earth is round?  Well, I dunno...  https://www.economist.com/blogs/graphicdetail/2017/11/daily-chart-21

Comment: I think you're looking for a tilted or oblique perspective projection. We don't have it in ArcGIS yet. As you've found, vertical near-side perspective, orthographic, or possibly the new geostationary satellite projection (10.6).

Comment: Interestingly, the World_Vertical_Perspective coordinate system that I used has as part of its description "Height: 35800000.0".  This value converts to 22,245 miles, which is darned close to the 22,236 miles that Wikipedia states as the altitude for geosynchronous satellites!